# What does "error code:4004" mean?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, wcf-data-services

I have this class

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


  namespace BusinessApplication3.Web
   {
     public class Query2
      {

    public Int32? IDENTETE_BL { get; set; }
    public String NO_BL { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DATE_BL { get; set; }
    public String FAC_AVOIR { get; set; }
    public String REF_BL { get; set; }
    public String CODE_CLIENT { get; set; }
    public String NOM_CLIENT { get; set; }
    public String ADRESSE { get; set; }
    public String CODE_PAYS { get; set; }
    public String VILLE { get; set; }
    public String CODE_POSTAL { get; set; }
    public String ZONE { get; set; }
    public String TEL_FAX { get; set; }
    public String CODE_ADL { get; set; }
    public String NOM_ADL { get; set; }
    public String ADRESSE_ADL { get; set; }
    public String CODE_POSTAL_ADL { get; set; }
    public String VILLE_ADL { get; set; }
    public Decimal? MT_TTC_BL { get; set; }
    public String CODE_PAYS_ADL { get; set; }
    public String TEL_FAX_ADL { get; set; }
    public Decimal? REM { get; set; }
    public String CODE_REGLEMENT { get; set; }
    public String NO_FACTURE { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DATE_FACTURE { get; set; }
    public String CODE_COMPTA { get; set; }
    public String SITE { get; set; }
    public String CODE_COMMERCIAL { get; set; }
    public Int32? NBR_COLIS { get; set; }
    public String NOM_TRANSPORTEUR { get; set; }
    public String FACTURE_DIRECTE { get; set; }
    public String MOIS_FACTURE { get; set; }
    public String CLE_SITE_MOIS_FAC { get; set; }
    public String CLE_SITE_FD_CC { get; set; }
    public String CLE_SITE_FD { get; set; }
    public String CLE_SITE_FD_CC_EDIT { get; set; }
    public String ARCHIVAGE { get; set; }
    public String NO_TVA_CL { get; set; }
    public String numero { get; set; }
    public String Bis { get; set; }
    public String voie { get; set; }
    public String P_identite { get; set; }
    public String p_numero { get; set; }
    public DateTime? p_du { get; set; }
    public String p_par { get; set; }
    public DateTime? nais_du { get; set; }
    public String nais_ville { get; set; }
    public String nais_dep { get; set; }
    public String nais_pays { get; set; }
    public String num_siren { get; set; }
    public Int64? id_bon_ademe { get; set; }
    public Decimal? poids_ademe_vhu { get; set; }
    public String CODE_BROYEUR { get; set; }
    public Int32 IDLIGNES_BL { get; set; }
    public String CODE_CLIENT_LI { get; set; }
    public String NO_BL_LI { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DATE_BL_LI { get; set; }
    public String FAC_AVOIR_LI { get; set; }
    public String CODE_ARTICLE { get; set; }
    public String NO_VEHICULE { get; set; }
    public String DESIGNATION { get; set; }
    public Decimal? QTE { get; set; }
    public Decimal? PU_HT { get; set; }
    public Decimal? REM_LI { get; set; }
    public String CODE_TVA { get; set; }
    public Single? TAUX_TVA { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public String NO_LIGNE { get; set; }
    public String TYPE_ARTICLE { get; set; }
    public String LIB_LIBRE { get; set; }
    public String DESI_ARTICLE { get; set; }
    public String CODE_GARANTIE { get; set; }
    public String NO_FACTURE_LI { get; set; }
    public String CODE_REGLEMENT_LI { get; set; }
    public String SITE_LI { get; set; }
    public String LIB_MODELE { get; set; }
    public Decimal? PA_HT_TTC { get; set; }
    public Decimal? PU_NET { get; set; }
    public Decimal? PU_TTC { get; set; }
    public Int64? code_id_article { get; set; }
    public String site_stockage { get; set; }
    public Byte? sans_trait_haut { get; set; }
    public String nom_article_unique_demonter { get; set; }
    public Int64? code_ademe_ligne { get; set; }
    public Decimal? poids_ademe { get; set; }
    public String type_article_ademe { get; set; }
    public String consistance { get; set; }
    public String conditionnement { get; set; }
    public Int64? nombre_carcasse { get; set; }
    public Int64? num_vehicule_entretien { get; set; }
    public String num_immat_vehi_entretien { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

and this function in my domainservice

```
   public IQueryable<Query2> Getligne_req()
    {
        return from t in ObjectContext.lignes_bl
               from t0 in ObjectContext.entete_bl
               where
                 t.NO_BL == t0.NO_BL
               orderby
                 t.NO_BL,
                 t.NO_LIGNE
               select new Query2()
               {
                   IDENTETE_BL = t0.IDENTETE_BL,
                   NO_BL = t0.NO_BL,
                   DATE_BL = t0.DATE_BL,
                   FAC_AVOIR = t0.FAC_AVOIR,
                   REF_BL = t0.REF_BL,
                   CODE_CLIENT = t0.CODE_CLIENT,
                   NOM_CLIENT = t0.NOM_CLIENT,
                   ADRESSE = t0.ADRESSE,
                   CODE_PAYS = t0.CODE_PAYS,
                   VILLE = t0.VILLE,
                   CODE_POSTAL = t0.CODE_POSTAL,
                   ZONE = t0.ZONE,
                   TEL_FAX = t0.TEL_FAX,
                   CODE_ADL = t0.CODE_ADL,
                   NOM_ADL = t0.NOM_ADL,
                   ADRESSE_ADL = t0.ADRESSE_ADL,
                   CODE_POSTAL_ADL = t0.CODE_POSTAL_ADL,
                   VILLE_ADL = t0.VILLE_ADL,
                   MT_TTC_BL = t0.MT_TTC_BL,
                   CODE_PAYS_ADL = t0.CODE_PAYS_ADL,
                   TEL_FAX_ADL = t0.TEL_FAX_ADL,
                   REM = t0.REM,
                   CODE_REGLEMENT = t0.CODE_REGLEMENT,
                   NO_FACTURE = t0.NO_FACTURE,
                   DATE_FACTURE = t0.DATE_FACTURE,
                   CODE_COMPTA = t0.CODE_COMPTA,
                   SITE = t0.SITE,
                   CODE_COMMERCIAL = t0.CODE_COMMERCIAL,
                   NBR_COLIS = t0.NBR_COLIS,
                   NOM_TRANSPORTEUR = t0.NOM_TRANSPORTEUR,
                   FACTURE_DIRECTE = t0.FACTURE_DIRECTE,
                   MOIS_FACTURE = t0.MOIS_FACTURE,
                   CLE_SITE_MOIS_FAC = t0.CLE_SITE_MOIS_FAC,
                   CLE_SITE_FD_CC = t0.CLE_SITE_FD_CC,
                   CLE_SITE_FD = t0.CLE_SITE_FD,
                   CLE_SITE_FD_CC_EDIT = t0.CLE_SITE_FD_CC_EDIT,
                   ARCHIVAGE = t0.ARCHIVAGE,
                   NO_TVA_CL = t0.NO_TVA_CL,
                   numero = t0.numero,
                   Bis = t0.bis,
                   P_identite = t0.P_identite,
                   p_numero = t0.p_numero,
                   p_du = t0.p_du,
                   p_par = t0.p_par,
                   nais_du = t0.nais_du,
                   nais_ville = t0.nais_ville,
                   nais_dep = t0.nais_dep,
                   nais_pays = t0.nais_pays,
                   num_siren = t0.num_siren,
                   id_bon_ademe = t0.id_bon_ademe,
                   poids_ademe_vhu = t0.poids_ademe_vhu,
                   CODE_BROYEUR = t0.CODE_BROYEUR,
                   IDLIGNES_BL = t.IDLIGNES_BL,
                   CODE_CLIENT_LI = t.CODE_CLIENT,
                   NO_BL_LI = t.NO_BL,
                   DATE_BL_LI = t.DATE_BL,
                   FAC_AVOIR_LI = t.FAC_AVOIR,
                   CODE_ARTICLE = t.CODE_ARTICLE,
                   NO_VEHICULE = t.NO_VEHICULE,
                   DESIGNATION = t.DESIGNATION,
                   QTE = t.QTE,
                   PU_HT = t.PU_HT,
                   REM_LI = t.REM,
                   CODE_TVA = t.CODE_TVA,
                   TAUX_TVA = t.TAUX_TVA,
                   NO_LIGNE = t.NO_LIGNE,
                   TYPE_ARTICLE = t.TYPE_ARTICLE,
                   LIB_LIBRE = t.LIB_LIBRE,
                   DESI_ARTICLE = t.DESI_ARTICLE,
                   CODE_GARANTIE = t.CODE_GARANTIE,
                   NO_FACTURE_LI = t.NO_FACTURE,
                   CODE_REGLEMENT_LI = t.CODE_REGLEMENT,
                   SITE_LI = t.SITE,
                   LIB_MODELE = t.LIB_MODELE,
                   PA_HT_TTC = t.PA_HT_TTC,
                   PU_NET = t.PU_NET,
                   PU_TTC = t.PU_TTC,
                   code_id_article = t.code_id_article,
                   site_stockage = t.site_stockage,
                   sans_trait_haut = t.sans_trait_haut,
                   nom_article_unique_demonter = t.nom_article_unique_demonter,
                   code_ademe_ligne = t.code_ademe_ligne,
                   poids_ademe = t.poids_ademe,
                   type_article_ademe = t.type_article_ademe,
                   consistance = t.consistance,
                   conditionnement = t.conditionnement,
                   nombre_carcasse = t.nombre_carcasse,
                   num_vehicule_entretien = t.num_vehicule_entretien,
                   num_immat_vehi_entretien = t.num_immat_vehi_entretien
               };


    }
```

I get error code:4004. what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a promising thread:

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/208030/496837.aspx

Sorry I can't help much beyond that.  From there it appears to be an authentication/authorization issue with windows integrity.